# Printing a Decimal Number

Tags: c, decimal

I am new to C language. Please help me out.
  I am writing a program which takes decimal numbers and traversing them to find the sum of             digits.

For Example,     233.1234 is the input
                 sum = 18 is the output

Thank you

My code so far

```
void main()
{
    float num;
    printf("Enter the decimal number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("%10.10d",num);
}
```

prints 0000000000
 Can anyone tell me how to print ?
Thank you

Comment: (Quick before it closes the type of number you want is call "floating point". Googling printing floating point numbers will help you figure this out!)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how *you* tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us *exactly* what the result was and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you really need to read.

Comment: Please look above I  have written my code and output.
Read carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Following is the program

    #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {

      //float f = 233.1234;
      float f;
      float s;
      int x;
      int unit = 0;

      printf("Enter the decimal number \n");
      scanf("%f",&f);

      printf("Entered the decimal number =%f\n",f);

      s = f;

       while((int)s % 10) {
         s = s*10;
       }
       x = (int) s/10;

       printf("x=%d,s=%f \n",x,s);

       while(x % 10) {
         unit = unit + (x % 10);
         x = x / 10;
       }

       printf("Sum of the digit = %d \n",unit);


    }



// output in the terminal

Enter the decimal number 
233.1234
Entered the decimal number =233.123398
x=2331234,s=23312340.000000 
Sum of the digit = 18
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer, rather than just code alone. Our goal here is to educate people so that they understand the answer and can apply it in other situations. If you comment your code and add an explanation, you will make your answer more helpful not just to the person who asked the question this time, but to anyone in the future who may be having the same problem.

Comment: Very good and simple answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    double num;
    char input[32], *p;
    printf("Enter the decimal number : ");
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    num = strtod(input, &p);
    if(*p=='\n'){
        int n, sum = 0;
        printf("input : %s", input);
        for(p = input; *p ; ++p){
            if(1==sscanf(p, "%1d", &n))
                sum += n;
        }
        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```